# Python Bottle web app to display output on browser in Realtime

Tags: python, bottle

I'm trying to build a bottle based Download Manager using pySmartDL.
But, i'm unable to output the progress bar to browser during download.

**app.py**

```
from bottle import route, run, debug, template, request, static_file, error
import os
from pySmartDL import SmartDL

@route('/static/:filename#.*#')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./static/')

@route('/',method='GET')
def index():
    return template('index.tpl')

@route('/download/', method='POST')
def result():
    if request.POST.get('url','').strip():
        url = request.POST.get('url', '').strip()
        #url = "http://mirror.ufs.ac.za/7zip/9.20/7za920.zip"
        dest = "C:\\Downloads\\" # or '~/Downloads/' on linux
        obj = SmartDL(url, dest)
        obj.start(blocking=None)
        # [*] 0.23 Mb / 0.37 Mb @ 88.00Kb/s [##########--------] [60%, 2s left]
        path = obj.get_dest()
        out = template('out',out=obj.get_progress_bar(length=20),path=path)
        return out
@error(500)
def mistake500(code):
    return '<h3>Error!</h3>'
debug(True)
run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

As soon as the file is downloaded, ############# is printed in browser.

**out.tpl**

```
% include('header.tpl', title='VTU Results Hub')
<table  class="pure-table">
{{out}}
{{path}}
</table>
% include('footer.tpl')
```

Is there any way so that i can display the progress bar in Real Time on Browser.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to start a background thread that downloads the file in the background...

in your HTML put (will make refresh every 5 seconds)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;    URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/status/">
```

In you .py file create status handler and post the updates...

```
@route('/status/', method='GET')
def result():
    #get the bar and return your template again...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this server-side, using asynchronous events processing with `gevents`. In fact, bottlepy documentation has a sample for this at http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()

from time import sleep
from bottle import route, run

@route('/stream')
def stream():
    yield 'START'
    sleep(3)
    yield 'MIDDLE'
    sleep(5)
    yield 'END'

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, server='gevent')
```

Also check out previously asked & answered SO question here: [Streaming Connection Using Python Bottle, Multiprocessing, and gevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318608/streaming-connection-using-python-bottle-multiprocessing-and-gevent)