# using for loops with bottle

Tags: python, for-loop, bottle

I am currently developing a python web-app based on [bottle](http://bottlepy.org) so what I am trying to do is print the outcome of a for loop I have tried the following

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bottle import *
@route('/')
def index():
    for i in range(10):
         return i
```

but this did not work and i got this from the development server output

```
localhost - - [13/Jan/2017 18:11:38] "GET /request HTTP/1.1" 200 0
localhost - - [13/Jan/2017 18:11:40] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

so i tried this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bottle import *
@route('/')
def index():
    sumOfValues=0
    for i in range(10):
        sumOfValues+=i
    return sumOfValues
```

this also did not work 
and my devlopment server gave me this

```
localhost - - [13/Jan/2017 18:15:44] "GET /request HTTP/1.1" 500 746
localhost - - [13/Jan/2017 18:15:46] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 750
```

so how can I do it I tried searching google but nothing came back
, thanks in advance

Comment: log shows that you call page `/request` but in code you define only `/` - it's two different addresses.

Comment: function has to return string - so use `return str(sumOfValues)`

Comment: Your first method worked better than the other. It returned 200 status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function has to return string - so use `return str(sumOfValues)`

Comment: Or just `return(str(sum(range(10)))`

Answer (score 0):

If you `return` in a function, it immediately ends.

It looks like you want to do a streaming response of-sorts. Bottle can do this, but you must [`yield` items](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.10/async.html?highlight=yield).

See also:

- [Streaming Connection Using Python Bottle, Multiprocessing, and gevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318608/streaming-connection-using-python-bottle-multiprocessing-and-gevent)